# Set default content in PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField

Tags: development, error, publishing, richhtmlfield

I need to add default content in the `PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField`.

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" runat="server" ID="welcomeText">
</PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
```

Above code doesn't accept any extra html.

So I tried using:

```
<PublishingWebControls:HtmlEditor ID="htmlEditor"  runat="server" />
        <div ID="HtmlEditorTextBox" visible="false" runat="server" >
        </div>
```

and in back-end using c#:

```
htmlEditor.Field = new RichHtmlField();
htmlEditor.Field.HasInitialFocus = false;
htmlEditor.Field.ControlMode = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControlMode.New;
htmlEditor.Field.EnableViewState = true;
//htmlEditor.Field.AllowReusableContent = false;
//htmlEditor.Field.MinimumEditHeight = "200px";
string text = Regex.Replace(OSSUtility.GetGlobalLocalizedString("UserControl_WelcomeMessage_Text"), @"\[([^\]]+)\]", OSSContext.Current.ClientName);
htmlEditor.Html = text;
HtmlEditorTextBox.InnerHtml = text;
```

I get the right result. But, I got an error while I tried editing the page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried putting the html in the `Value` attribute on `<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>`?

Comment: <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="xx" runat="server" ID="welcomeText" Value=""> and in c# : welcomeText.Value= "html div", error : Cannot create an object of type 'System.Object' from its string representation '' for the 'Value' property.

Comment: using c#, i used welcomeText.Value , welcomeText.html and welcomeText.text , and i got nothing

Comment: The contents of these fields are technically metadata of the list item of the page, so I don't think I can set default content in the page layout itself, I would need to set the content in the list items of pages that use your layout.